# Multiple methods named 'setYear' found with mismatch result

Tags: objective-c, mismatch

I'm a beginner of Objective C, trying to write a simple program print the birth year of a person, but there is an error "Multiple methods named 'setYear' found with mismatch result", can anyone help me figure out why it happens?

```
//person.h
@interface person : NSObject
@property int year;
+ (id)person;
@property (readonly) NSString* summary;
@end

//  main.m
#import "person.h"
@implementation person
@synthesize year;
+ (id)book{
    person *somePerson = [[self alloc] init];
    return somePerson;
}

- (NSString*)summary{
    NSNumber* yearAsObject;
    yearAsObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.year];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Borned in %@.", yearAsObject];
}
@end

int main(){
    @autoreleasepool {
        id aperson = [person person];
        [aperson setYear:@1970];
        NSLog (@"Birth year: %@", [aperson summary]);
    }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: One mistake is that, *year* is an int property. But you are passing *NSNumber* to *setYear:* method.

Comment: hi @EmptyStack, how to assign value to year? Thanks.

Comment: Change that line to ***[aperson setYear:1970];***. Note that @ is removed.

Comment: Off topic: Please stick to Objective-C naming conventions. It'll make your life easier. Particularly, class names should start with uppercase letters, so the class should be named `Person`.

Comment: @DarkDust, good warning, I just noticed that, will change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use the `id` type on variables if you know which type you're going to put there. That's because by using `id` instead of the real class name, the compiler simply doesn't know what kind of sanity checks to perform.

In this particular case, the compiler sees the method `setYear:` but since it doesn't know it should be a `person` object (please stick to Objective-C naming conventions and rename the class to `Person` instead), it looks up *all* methods called `setYear:` it can find. It'll find your property of type `int`, but it will also find [`-[NSDateComponents setYear:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateComponents/setYear%3a) which expects a `NSInteger`, which is either an `int` or `long`. If you're building for 64-bit, it'll be a `long`.

So now the compiler knows there exist two methods `setYear:`, one expects an `int`, the other a `long`. The compiler does not know which one you mean since the type of `aperson` is `id`.

There are two solutions: either put a cast in the call as in `[(person *)aperson setYear:1970]` (passing `@1970`, which is a `NSNumber`, is wrong here). The better solution is to actually tell the compiler your intention and specify the correct type of the variable:

```
person *aperson = [person person];
[person setYear:1970];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by correcting the `setYear:` method call. Your code in main method should be as follows:

```
int main(){
    @autoreleasepool {
        id aperson = [person person];
        [(person*)aperson setYear:1970];
        NSLog (@"Birth year: %@", [aperson summary]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Your problem gets solved by replacing id with the correct type of the sender (person * in this case), because the compiler then knows that sender is an instance of the person class, and therefore knows which `setYear:` method is applied here.

Comment: Hi @Vinay Jain, this solution works if I change `year` property to a `NSNumber`, but if it's an `int`, this doesn't work.

Comment: It works, thank you! But I still don't understand why. For example, if I have a property `@property NSString* name;`, why can I use `[aperson setName:@"Tom"];` to set, but for numbers I can't

Comment: @wuyefeibao : Because @ return NSNumber and you made a property for 'int'. Thats why you need to pass integer to the setter method. Please accept the answer.

Comment: @"Tom" is a shortcut that the compiler understands, and it will create an NSString* containing the characters Tom. @1970 is a shortcut that the compiler understands, and it will create an NSNumber* containing the number 1970. setName wants an NSString* so that's fine. setYear wants an integer, so an NSNumber* is _not_ fine.